# Finding The Limits of an Exponent Operation According to Order of Operations

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string containing an equation. I need to check the string to try to find an exponent and then locate the limits of that expression according to order of operations. I'm not really sure how to explain it, so here are some strings and expected outputs that demonstrate my goal:

- `2*(3+4)`: No matches (no exponent)
- `2^5`: The whole string is the exponent operation
- `4^7-6`: Find `4^7`
- `5+6^3`: Just find `6^3`
- `(5+6)^3`: The whole string is part of the exponent
- `(6+-4)^8`: The whole string is part of the exponent, including the negative number

Any of those numbers could also be a single letter variable, such as 'x'. There could be any mathematical operations on either side, so the only way to find the part that I want (that I know of) is to match a single number OR a pair of parenthesis. I would prefer to use a regex, but plain string manipulation is fine too. I was thinking about something like this (regex):
`[0-9a-z\.]\^[0-9a-z\.]`
But that doesn't accommodate for possible negative signs, nor will it allow grouping symbols like parenthesis (For this, you would need to make sure there were only matching pairs). There are a few other cases in which my attempt above would fail.

So what's the best way to do this? I don't have the expertise to know how to catch every case with a regex, and have no idea how to handle all the possibilities with pure JS.

Comment: Do you know how to write a parser for mathematical expressions?

Comment: Why you added `a-z` to the pattern?

Comment: @AvinashRaj Presumably for variable names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input conforms to what you mentioned, I would suggest something like this:

```
-?(?:[a-z]+|\d+|\([^()]+\))\^-?(?:[a-z]+|\d+|\([^()]+\))
```

**Sample matches:**

```
-2^3
2^3
2^(a/b)
(a+b)^7 
(a+b)^(d/c)
(5+6)^3
```

See the matches in [the demo](http://regex101.com/r/gY7rO4/42).

- in your code, make it case-insensitive by setting the `i` flag
- Note that JavaScript does not support recursion, so we are in trouble for nested parentheses as in `2^(3-(2/x))`

**Explanation**

- `-?` allows an optional minus sign
- `(?:[a-z]+|\d+|\([^()]+\))` matches a variable made of letters `[a-z]+`... OR '|`
- digits `\d+` OR `|`
- `\([^()]+\))` a set of parentheses
- `\^` matches the exponentiation operator
- the right side of the power matches tokens of the same kind we allowed on the left

**Option 2: `x^y^z...`**

If you want to allow `x^y^z...`, modify the regex like so:

```
-?(?:[a-z]+|\d+|\([^()]+\))(?:\^-?(?:[a-z]+|\d+|\([^()]+\)))+
```

Comment: FYI: added explanation, demo and sample matches. :)

Comment: Will your regex work for `2^3^4`? (I didn't look closely, so this is just an honest question.)

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below regex to get only the exponential part,

```
[a-z0-9]+(?:\^[a-z0-9]+)+|\([a-z0-9]+[-+*/]+[a-z0-9]+\)\^(?:[a-z0-9]+|\([a-z0-9]+[-+*/]+[a-z0-9]+\))
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/yQ5vG1/4)

Answer (score 1):

The language of mathematical expressions is not a regular language. You will need to write a parser of some sort rather than relying on regexes.